# Why does Coq rename variables in induction?

Tags: rename, coq

I'm trying to prove the following theorem.

```
Theorem subseq_trans : forall (l1 l2 l3 : list nat),
  subseq l1 l2 -> subseq l2 l3 -> subseq l1 l3.
Proof.
  intros l1 l2 l3 H12 H23. generalize dependent l1. (* here l2 l3 *) induction H23.
  - intros. inversion H12. apply empty.
  - (* here l1 l2 *) rename l2 into l3. rename l1 into l2. ...
```

In line 3 after `generalize dependent l1.` I have the following context:

```
l2, l3 : list nat
H23 : subseq l2 l3
```

But in line 5 before renames I have

```
l1, l2 : list nat
H23 : subseq l1 l2
IHsubseq : ...
```

So `l2` and `l3` became `l1` and `l2`. Why did it happen? How can I prevent this from happening?

I don't think it's important, but `subseq` is defined like this:

```
Inductive subseq : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
  | empty l : subseq [] l
  | first x l1 l2 (H : subseq l1 l2) : subseq (x :: l1) (x :: l2)
  | skip x l1 l2 (H : subseq l1 l2) : subseq l1 (x :: l2).
```

My Coq version:

```
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.8.2 (January 2019)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's renamed to `l1` and `l2` because that's the name given in the definition of `subseq`. To fix this you can name the variables explicitly when doing the induction:

`induction H23 as [ | ? l2 l3 | ].`

Here there are 3 cases for `subseq`, so you need 3 branches. I've only named the lists for the `first` case, so I've left the names blank for the other cases and used `?` once, both of which which tell Coq to use the default naming.

Comment: I feel it would be better to just say `[ | ? l2 l3 | ]`. Variables that don’t get a name are given their default name by default, as it were. Also, as each `?` only binds one variable, it feels slightly "dishonest" to use a sole `?` in a branch to represent that *all* variables in that branch take their default names.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers! I also see that my understanding of what happens was completely wrong.